# Not able to view diff for mercurial repo on Review Board

Tags: python, mercurial, review-board

I have configured a local mercurial repo on the Review Board server.
I am also using the `mercurial-reviewboard` extension to generate review requests, which is working fine.

I am facing problems while viewing the diff for a Review Request.

I am using the following tools:

```
Review Board : 1.6.6
Apache 2.2
Mercurial 1.9
```

One thing I noted is, the temp file which is generated does not have a `-new` at the end
As mentioned below file `tmppftuho` exists but `tmppftuho-new` does not

`tmppftuho` looks exactly as the source file.

Following is the stack trace:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\windows\\temp\\reviewboard.nq6s0i\\tmppftuho-new'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reviewboard\diffviewer\views.py", line 151, in view_diff
    interdiffset, highlighting, True)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reviewboard\diffviewer\diffutils.py", line 1072,     in get_diff_files
    large_data=True)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\djblets\util\misc.py", line 157, in cache_memoize
data = lookup_callable()
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reviewboard\diffviewer\diffutils.py", line 1071, in <lambda>
    enable_syntax_highlighting)),
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reviewboard\diffviewer\diffutils.py", line 552, in get_chunks
    old = get_original_file(filediff)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reviewboard\diffviewer\diffutils.py", line 369, in get_original_file
    data = patch(filediff.parent_diff, data, filediff.source_file)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reviewboard\diffviewer\diffutils.py", line 245, in patch
    f = open(newfile, "r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\windows\\temp\\reviewboard.nq6s0i\\tmppftuho-new'
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. GNUWin32 patch which is used by Review Board is only available for x86 machines, I tried downloading diffutils source and building it but the file seems corrupted :( Does anyone know any other mirror site other than [link](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/diffutils/) where I can download diffutils 3.3 source